# How can i solve this error in Unity Curl error 3: url malformed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webrequest

I'm trying to get the url from the php page where am I going wrong? Error is: Curl error 3: malformed

my php file output :  https://akdenizsergi.com/yetki/uploads/test3.jpg

my php code:

```
<?php
echo "test3.jpg"
 ?>
```

my gettext code(C#):

```
  IEnumerator GetText()
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://localhost/yetki/eserlistesi2.php");

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        // Show results as text
        eserurl = www.downloadHandler.text;

        

       
    }
}
```

my get texture code:

```
IEnumerator GetTexture()
{

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(eserurl);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log("hata" + www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        myTexture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)www.downloadHandler).texture;
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material = myMat;

        // texture ı material e atıyor
        myMat.mainTexture = myTexture;

        // görsel ölçüsünü ekrana yazdırıyor
        print("Size is " + myTexture.width + " by " + myTexture.height);

        // plane ölçüsünü görselin ölçüsüne göre ayarlıyor
        myPlane.transform.localScale += new Vector3(myTexture.width, 0, myTexture.height);


    }
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `eserurl`?

Comment: <?php
echo "https://akdenizsergi.com/yetki/uploads/test3.jpg"
 ?>

Comment: IEnumerator GetText()
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://localhost/yetki/eserlistesi2.php");

        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            // Show results as text
            eserurl = www.downloadHandler.text;

            

           
        }
    }

Comment: Well theres why then. It doesnt have a valid url. Im also surprised it has any path info in it not just the test3.jpg

Comment: how can i fix :/ i dont get it can you explain more